# How can I get multiple layer in JSON format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

I am using rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.1.5

I create two table  1.API(name:string) and 2.Description(key:string, value:string).For relation, API has_many Datas.

Below is my index action of controller for return data in JSON format.

```
def show
  @api = Api.find(params[:id])
  @descriptions = @api.descriptions.all
  data = {}
  @descriptions.each do |f|
    data[f.key] = f.value
  end
  render json: data, :except => [:created_at, :id, :api_id ]
end
```

And it may return data in JSON  like:

```
{
  "country":"USA"
  "City":"NY"
}
```

My question is how should I get data like below( multiple JSON data).

```
{
  "country":{
                "Taiwan":"Taipei",
                "China":"Hong Kong",
                "England":"Londan"
            },

  "password_type":"known",
  "password":"123456"
}
```

How should I re-design my database or any another way?

Comment: Could you post the data `@description` object has?

Comment: Descriptions table has two column (key and value).In view template, I design a input box can let user input there value.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to implement template handler for that. Ryan Bates has recorded a great screencast on them, check this out: [Railscasts PRO #379 Template Handlers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnw14mjhLk) (there is also an associated github repo with an example app [here](https://github.com/railscasts/379-template-handlers)).

With that in mind you simply end a controller action rendering a `json.rb` template, which contains the following trick:

```
# app/views/apis/show.json.rb

def list_of_countries
  @descriptions.inject({}) do |result, object|
    result[object["country"]] = object["city"]
    result
  end
  # => {"USA": "NY", "Great Britain": "London"}
end

{
  country: list_of_countries,
  password_type: @password_type # I assume you've set this up in controller
}.end.to_json
# {country: {"USA": "NY", "Great Britain": "London"}, password_type: "salt"}
```